# Guidelines to create a framework for iPhone UIAutomation tool

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

Can some body share your thoughts to create a framework using iPhone UiAutomation tool (Instruments)

Comment: It is completely unclear to me what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this of interest:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/UI_Automation_Testing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to USE framework for testing with Automator, you can use [tuneup_js library](https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js) by Alex Vollmer.

Answer (score 0):

Download tuneupjs folder from github.com, it the framework you need to organize your scripts.

https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js